# Предлог к слову "класс"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Сначала я приведу аргументы, а после ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопрос.
Все мы знаем, что "класс" — это группа людей или помещение школы, а "курс" — отдельная годичная ступень образования или объем образования. Есть классные чины — специальные звания.

Представим деревенскую школу, где обучается менее 100 человек. Во всех классах обучаются по 3-10 учеников, но в 8 классе —- никого. Как быть? Если говорить "в 8 классе" — я считаю это ошибочным, потому что нет группы, нет коллектива.
Законодательно установлено 4 уровня образования (дошкольное, начальное, основное и среднее).
1 класс — 1 уровень;
2 класс — 2 уровень (или подуровень) и т. д.
Вопрос: можно ли говорить: "на классе"? Аргументируя это уровнем, степенью, курсом обучения (1 год — 1 класс).

Comment: В данном случае предусмотренного в школе 8 класса **нет** (в текущем году), поэтому вопроса о предлоге не должно возникать.

Answer (score 1):

Класс — это и номер (наименование), это и помещение, это и год в цикле всего курса обучения. Корректно (при нулевом числе учеников) говорить: «Класса восьмого года обучения нет».

Предлог *на* употребим со словом *класс*, — «на классе лежит ответственность», например. Но не в вашем случае: Отсутствие учеников делает бессмысленным существование любого предлога при слове *класс* в значении некоей группы людей.

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы говорим, что в 8-м классе не обучается ни один из деревенских, мы ставим во главу угла учеников (а не то, в какую школу они ходят и есть ли там 8-й класс). А если говорим о школе, то в ней нет в этом году 8-го класса. Можно сказать, в ней нет восьмиклассников.

Примечание. В записи порядковых числительных нужно использовать буквенное наращение: **8-й** класс.

Answer (score 0):

> Если говорить "в 8 классе" — я считаю это ошибочным, потому что нет
>   группы, нет коллектива.

Хотелось бы понять, какое отношение наличие/отсутствие "группы" имеет к выбору предлога.

Я правильно понимаю, что вы не возражаете против употребления "в восьмом классе кто-то есть", но если нет никого, то предлагаете говорить "на восьмом классе"?! Это весьма странное убеждение.

> Вопрос: можно ли говорить: "на классе"? Аргументируя это уровнем,
>   степенью, курсом обучения (1 год — 1 класс).

Нет. Нельзя ни говорить, ни аргументировать. 
Аргументировать можно только чем-то имеющим отношение к выбору предлога.  Чем И чем бы вы не аргументировали есть вполне понятная сематическая нагрузка предлога.

"На классе" можно кого-то обыграть в хоккей или преферанс. Но в чем смысл замены предлога в сочетании "находиться в" на неиспользуемый в данном случае?
Даже если допустить, что "класс" здесь синонимично "уровню" (что не так), это не диктует выбора предлога, не отменяет правила сочетаемости предлога.

А если "никого нет", допустим, в театре? В комнате? В партии любителей пива?